# How to change an array object without a reference to the array?

Tags: c#, arrays, reference

Let's say that I have an object of type `A` at index 5 of array `items` and I want to change it to be a new object of type `B`.

If I had a reference to the array, I could just do `items[5] = new B();` to change the item.

However, let's suppose that I only had the object at `items[5]` and not the reference to the array, and it's stored in a variable `item`. If I just do `item = new B();`, the change will not be reflected in the array, because only that variable will be changed.

Is it possible to change that item in such a way that the change will be reflected in the array, such that `items[5]` will contain that new item of type `B`?

Preferably something simple without the use of delegates or lambdas or the like because it is somewhat performance-critical.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in this case you should use [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

Demonstrating example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new  List<Sample>();
        list.Add(new SampleDerived(){ Age=2, DAge = 5 });
        list.Add(new SampleDerived(){ Age=3, DAge = 5 });
        list.Add(new SampleDerived(){ Age=4, DAge = 5 });
        list.Add(new SampleDerived(){ Age=5, DAge = 5 });
        list.Add(new SampleDerived(){ Age=6, DAge = 5 });
        var list2 = list.ToArray();
        Process(ref list2[2]);
        Console.WriteLine(list2[2].Age); // will print 10 not 4
    }

    public static void Process(ref Sample s)
    {
        s = new Sample(){Age=10};
    }
}
public class Sample
{
    public int Age {get; set;}
}

public class SampleDerived : Sample
{
    public int DAge {get; set;}
}
```

Dot net fiddler is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9CXiGv).

Comment: Process uses `list2[2]` as an argument. One of the requirements is that I only have access to the object and not the array or the item's index in the array.

Comment: How exactly did you get that object? Is it a reference to the object in the array or a copy of the object in the array?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev is is called pass by reference look at MSDN link for more detail.

Comment: It is a reference to the object in the array. That is, it's a different variable but points to the object in the array.

Comment: @NathanaëlRadomír I think it is not possible then. you will have to maintain some reference to the object before method call. You may go with pointer (unsafe code) but I would not recommend it.

Comment: It's possible with an action lambda but is too slow for my purposes.

Comment: @NathanaëlRadomír yes delegate may help you achieve that but you mentioned you are not looking for such a solution that involve delegates and lambdas!

Comment: @JenishRabadiya is right, if all you have is a copy of the reference to the object, then there is no way to modify the original reference in the array. If this were C code, that would be like having a pointer to a memory address and being able to modify someone else's pointer to that same location. *Something* will need to know about the array, and modify it directly or allow it to be modified.